# Most natural rating for users

Tags: jquery

Which system is more natural rating for users?

I have a website where people are goingt to rate the other user after the deal is complete.

Now, I am deciding between "classic" five star rating system where five stars is best and zero worst. So, it will look like e.g.:

User rating: 4.5 (plus a 4 and a half star image)

Or the percentage type rating where you type (manually or with a slider jQuery UI)

where people will choose a value from 0 to 100 percent and the result will look like after a couple votes like e.g.:

User rating: 96%

Which way do you prefer and why?

Can you recomend the most plugin for such voting using jquery? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you really want plugin for this simple task..

Comment: I mean for the animation part, I am not very good in this part.

Comment: If i were you then i must have used star method as it looks better and very easy to code

Comment: I think I will use it too, I am currently looking at phpacademy channel on youtube he has there a star rating tutorial. But I am definitely looking for other opinions why should e.g. the "percent" way be better or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Don't Make Me Think". It depends on whether you want to track the quality of an experience in a more granular fashion, or simply want to know whether someone prefers another person or just had a good experience or not.

Stars make sense when users want to portray the quality of something like a movie, book, or a product. What you are describing sounds much simpler than that.

You might just ask the reviewer "Would you do business with this person again or no?". A simple checkbox, yes or no (you could allow them to enter comments to explain why, if they so choose). Then you would average the number of people said yes. "96% of users would do business with this person again.". Not much of a plugin is needed, there.

Either way, definitely no sliders, combo boxes, whackamoles, or silly things like that. People can check boxes (or thumbs up, thumbs down, if that suits you better), and star ratings are intuitive to people. Stick with either of those.

Comment: Now, you completely changed my mind. But what are you saying makes sense. The strategy keep it simple make sense. I will stick with your suggestion and add an optional textarea for short review in a few words if somebody is interested. Maybe this simple solution will be the best, because two options are easier to deside than 5 ;). thanks for your comment. I appreciate your time.